# Is Sigma 17-70mm f/2.8-4 DC OS or Canon 17-55mm IS USM the better general purpose lens?

Tags: lens, canon, sigma

I'm looking for a new general purpose walk around lenses for my Canon XTI Rebel. Right now I have a the original Sigma 17-70 f/2.4-4.5 that does not have image stabilization, and looking to upgrade to a lens that does. I'd like to stick with a lens the can open up to a 2.8 aperture, and a wide focal length (15mm-20mm)

I've been reading a lot of reviews and have narrowed my choices down to the Canon EF-S 17-55 or the new Sigma 17-70 that has IS (or what sigma calls OS).

On B&H the 17-55 goes for $1099 and the 17-70 goes for $449. That's almost a 150% increase in price.

In comparison spec wise the 17-55 has a shorter zoom length, but also a constant 2.8 aperture and full time manual focus.

I've also been looking at the comparison shots on the-the-digital-picture.com, which seem to show that the 17-55 is a little sharper then the 17-70, but I'm really no expert at looking at these test shots, but they don't seem *that* different to me.

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=398&Camera=474&Sample=0&FLI=2&API=1&LensComp=713&CameraComp=474&SampleComp=0&FLIComp=2&APIComp=2

So what I'm trying to figure out is if the Canon  is really worth the extra $650 over the Sigma? Both have image stabilization but is the Sigma version as good as the canon version? What about the Sigma USM auto focus? Is it as good as Canon's? The difference in focal length is not a big deal to me, but I would appreciate the constant 2.8 aperture and FTMF of the Canon although I'm not sure if that's worth and extra $650 to me.

---

**Update**

Here's a few graphs I generated by running [ExposurePlot](http://www.cpr.demon.nl/prog_plotf.html) on my photos folder. As you can see most of my photos are wide angle, and wide aperture. Yet I also end up using a high ISO like 1600 a lot. I was hoping a lens with IS would allow me to handhold at slower shutter speeds and thus lower ISO.

From the answers so far it sounds like the Canon 17-55 might be worth the money over the Sigma. I've also been considering an L including the 24-70 and 24-105. But I honestly have no plans to upgrade to a full frame any time soon, nor require the build quality of an L.

[Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kX6Z.png)

[image]

Comment: Why do you need IS? Are you regularly shooting slower than 1/70th of a second at the far end of the lens?

Comment: Sligthly false assumption there I think, Joanne. 1/70 is optistic; it works (more or less) well on full-frame at 70 mm but the crop has to be factored in. I'd call it 1/140 just to be safe.

Comment: A 70mm lens is still a 70mm lens. The crop doesn't change the focal length of the lens, just the angle of view. Besides, your math doesn't add up, a 1.5 crop has the same angle of view as a 105mm on a FF sensor, so worse case it's about 1/100.

Comment: A 70mm lens may still be a 70mm lens, but the crop factor does have to be taken into account when discussing blur from camera shake. A 44mm lens with a 1/3.5" sensor is going to be way more subject to camera shake than a 44mm lens on a 35mm sensor.

Comment: As a side note... as a smoker, my hands are hardly steady as a rock and the 1/focal rule still works for me on an APS-C.

Comment: @Evan Krall - No, the crop factor won't, the pixel density may have an impact, but an APS-C with the same pixel density as a FF is simply a crop and won't have the same impact. I think this is where people confuse the two. A tightly packed sensor is more sensitive to movement, but this isn't directly related to the size of the sensor, and so the sensor size can't be directly translated to some of the classic shooting rules.

Comment: I tested one day and there's a huge difference in blur on my 50mm between 1/50th and 1/80th...even when trying to be steady, the 1/50th was at the edge of acceptable.  I've switched to taking the crop factor into account for my steady calculations...

Comment: In any case, the question is still valid... Paying for IS under 100mm seems like a total waste of money to me unless you're seriously jittery. At those focal lengths it is a crutch for not using good form when shooting and the evidence I'll use for that is about 100 years of photography without image stabilization...

Comment: JoanneC: Definitely, especially with a wide aperture.

Comment: @rfusca - There are techniques, somewhat in common with rifle shooting, that can change a lot of this. When I was doing the military gig (got to the exalted rank of Lieutenant) the trick to a steady shot was to take up the slack on the trigger and then gently squeeze to fire the round. Conscious attempts to do this at first leads to doing it generally and I went from an okay shot to marksman with that effort. The same, basic, principles apply to photography.

Comment: JoanneC: I have some rifle training and am familiar with some steadying techniques (both positions and breathing) - though I would not by any means call myself a marksman.  I just found the 80mm to be more of my threshold, perhaps I'm just pickier than the average bear.

Comment: @rfusca - The lens matters as well, but mileage varies by person in any case, including using the 1/focal rule. I just generally object to blindly using the crop factor as a multiplier, it isn't always the case. An 18mp APS-C and a 10mp APS-C are not the same beast and to treat them the same when it comes to sensor size is naive.

Comment: JoanneC: True enough.

Comment: I really want the IS more to be able to hand hold at slower shutter speeds in low light because right now I tend to increase the ISO which of course results in more noise. I'm looking into getting a wide angle fast prime as well.

Comment: These kinds of questions are impossible for us to answer. You are asking if something is worth the money, but we don't know how much you value your money or your lens. Some people fly economy class and others fly first class; no one choice is more "correct".

Comment: @rm999 I agree these questions are hard to answer, sorry. Although, I'm not expecting people to know if something is worth it to me. Rather I'm trying to understand why these two lenses, which have very similar specifications, are priced so differently.

Comment: The 1/focal length rule is really more about *angle of view* than focal length so the crop factor **does** come into play. On a 1.6x body the same amount of movement will move the subject 60% more as a percentage of the height of the frame. The pixel pitch will not affect it if the display size is the same for both images. Only at 100% crops (1 pixel to 1 pixel comparison) does the pixel pitch come into play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget the Sigma for using it wide-open. From experience, the maximum aperture is more a last-resort kind of thing there. Mine was extremely soft at 2.8, so I basically considered it an F/4.5-5.6 lens! Really, without stopping down by at least one stop, it wasn't pretty.

On the other hand, the Canon 17-55mm F/2.8 is really superb. Wide open it is good, and stopped down to F/4, it is extremely sharp.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything about the Canon lens, I looked pretty hard at the Sigma lens when making my last purchase.  I ultimately decided against it because several reviews said that 2.8 wide aperture quickly shrunk and was more marketing than useful, except at exactly 17mm.

If the wide aperture is important, I'd lean towards the Canon.

Comment: Yes as you can see from my update above, wide aperture is important. Thanks for the suggestion .. even if it will probably cost me $600+

Answer (score 0):

I have the Canon 17-55.  It replaced a Tamron 28-75.  Even discounting the IS feature (which I find helps in low light), 28mm the Canon is better than the Tamron was across the board.  If you get the 17-55 you won't regret the quality of the lens.

You might wish it were a bit longer on the long side, but I wanted a wide fast lens and it sounds like you do too.  That's an expensive place to be.

FYI: something else you might consider in this space are prime lenses (fixed focal length).  My favorite prime lens is a Sigma 30 f/1.4 (the Canon 28 f/1.8 is also very competitive). They are good lenses, a bit different for walking around, but lots of folks like them and use them for the walk around lenses.